# what does כל כבודה בת מלך פנימה refer to?

Tags: tznius-modesty

I always assumed that כל כבודה בת מלך פנימה (Tehillim 45:14) refers to a girl remaining at home, and that is how the mefarshim seem to explain it (Ibn Ezra and Radak). However, I hear it used primarily as a reference to the way girls must *dress*.

Is there a source for such an explanation?

Comment: Consider dropping the last part of the question _why is the typical explanation commonly ignored_ as a) questions should be limited to a single query, additional queries are best asked separately. b) it seems mostly opinion based, and hard to objectively answer. c) it asks about common sentiment rather than Judaism. Consider learning more about the site from this short useful [Beginners' Guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Comment: _Is there a source for such an explanation_ do you mean that it refers to dress _elusively_, or that it refers to general modesty which includes modest dress?

Comment: Maybe it's a nasal letter-flip with the singular of פנינים and it refers to a jewel, like the verses surrounding it. Remember Kevuddah means "wealth" like Judges 18:21 וַיָּשִׂימוּ אֶת-הַטַּף וְאֶת-הַמִּקְנֶה וְאֶת-הַכְּבוּדָּה לִפְנֵיהֶם (not unlike the the usage in a couple weeks וּמֵאֲשֶׁר לְאָבִינוּ עָשָׂה אֵת כָּל-הַכָּבֹד הַזֶּה). Indeed the Targum to that verse translates Kol Kevuddah as כל שפר ארג נכסי, a phrase familiar to us from the Ketubbah where the husband promises to pay off the Ketubbah from all his wealth. (Even if פנימה does mean inside, recall the queen didn't control land.)

Answer (score 1):

Just read the end of the verse .. "ממשבצות זהב לבושה ".. you can see it refers to the dress.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your answer.

Comment: see commentators, that explain ממשבצות זהב לבושה to mean the reward or the result of כל כבודה בת בלך מנימה, not an elaboration.

Comment: see the מצודות דוד:
"כל כבודה" - כל אשה מכובדה ובת מלך היושבת פנימה בחדרה לפי רוב כבודה אשר לבושה עשוי ממשבצות זהב